# how to use a raw_input as argument in a function in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, variables, input, arguments, raw-input

I'm trying to write a simple program with python 3 for practice. What I want to do is draw a function that takes an user `input()` as argument. I have tried storing the `input()` in a variable, but everytime I try to proceed the variable calls itself asking for the `input()`, so it doesn't store anything. I have also tried something like this:

```
def function(input('give me a '), input('give me b ')):
    # do stuff with the inputs
```

but it gives syntax error in the parenthesis.

Any idea on how to set a function to use user's `input()` as arguments?

Comment: You should add your sample program demonstrating how exactly do you reference things and attempt to process them. For example, your `def function` is syntactically incorrect, as it must list the argument names — not the actions performed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. Most likely you want to pass the user input to the function call rather than the definition:

```
def function(a, b):
    print(a, b)

a = input('give me a ')
b = input('give me b ')

function(a, b)
```

However, if you want to pass a given user input as the default argument to a function, you could do it like this:

```
def function(a=input('give me a '), b=input('give me b ')):
    print(a, b)

function()  # prints whatever the user inputted when the file was initially run
```

The reason your code raises an exception is because the content in the `()` in a function *definition* (as opposed to a function *call*, i.e., `function()`) is the *names* of the parameters rather than the arguments passed to the function. You can use `input()` in this part of the function signature only if you assign it as a default value to be associated with a parameter name, as I did above. This second use case seems pretty strange though, and every time `function()` is called it will be passed the same arguments as defaults that the user initially entered. Even if that is what you want to do, you should probably do this instead:

```
input_a = input('give me a ')
input_b = input('give me b ')

def function(a=input_a, b=input_b:
    print(a, b)

function()
```

Alternatively, if you want to get a different pair of inputs every time the function is called (this actually seems most likely now that I think about it):

```
def function():
    a = input('give me a ')
    b = input('give me b ')
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: Something that's not obvious about `def f(a=input()):` is that the default arguments are evaluated immediately when the function definition is evaluated (and not when first called or anything).

Comment: @JoshLee right, this is something that I never really thought about before answering this question. It seems both intuitive and counter-intuitive at the same time to me, because the *body* of the function is not evaluated until it is called.

Comment: Or `def func(a=None):a = input('give me a') if a is None else a; ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should know that inputs are considered as strings. When you want to use their value, try doing `int()` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the named arguments with them set to default values with input(), it seems that all the parameters have to be inputs as well. But if you set a variable to a default value without input, that can be used with just other variables as parameters.